# Android:Refresh accesstoken using asynchronous call in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, access-token, retrofit2

I am developing an android application which requires `accesstoken` for all `api calls`. `AccessToken` expires after every 10 min.I am using `retrofit` for `api calls`.Currently what i am doing is first getting an `accesstoken` using `getAccessToken()` method and in response I make other `api calls` so it confirms the other `api calls`(like getting user information) are made only after getting `accesstoken`. This works fine but as there are lots of api calls in my app i need to write the same code of `getAccessToken()` method in every class(fragment or activity) and the corresponding `api calls` in the response.
So is there any way to avoid this duplicate code in every class or i am doing the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Try a static function.

```
public class Utility {
    public static String getAccessToken(Context context) {
        //Do the calculation here
        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

Invoke this method in whenever you need accessToken from your activity or from fragments by

```
Utility.getAccessToken(context);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use
[Retrofit Interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors).

than every request which use retrofit passes through your interseptor gets your access_token.

it will looks like that in your interceptor:

```
Request request = chain.request();
request.header("header_name", Utility.getAccessToken());
Response response = chain.proceed(request);
```

Comment: the question is how to make an async call in `Interceptor` class